How do I ssh-copy-id to a different user from the user used to establish a connection?
I can currently ssh into a remote machine with root access using a specified identity file: root-identity-file.pem
I'm setting up a new linux user for ssh login. I've created a new keypair new-key.pem, new-key.pub on the local machine.
I want to move new-key.pub to /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys. The PubkeyAuthentication yes is in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
I've tried to do this two ways:
First way
Add a section to .ssh/config on the local machine:
Match user root-identity.
    IdentityFile root-identity-file.pem
Then ssh-copy-id -f -i new-key.pub -o "User root-identity" new-user@remotehost
This fails with:
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: new-key.pub
Permission denied (publickey).
Second way
ssh -i root-identity-file.pem root@10.44.32.194 'cat >> /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys' < new-key.pub
This fails as permission denied because the root user doesn't have permission to write to the new users authorized_keys file.
Variations of Second way
ssh -i root-identity-file.pem root@10.44.32.194 'su - new-user && cat >> /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys' < new-key.pub
ssh -i root-identity-file.pem root@10.44.32.194 'echo pwd | su - new-user && cat >> /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys' < new-key.pub
This feels like a bit of a chicken-or-the-egg situation. Is it possible to use an existing ssh login to add a key to another user?

If you can already log in to the remote device as root, then that is the way to deliver the new ssh key.

I want to move new-key.pub to /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Because this is a new user account we will need to create the .ssh directory and populate a new instance of authorized_keys with the new key. (This is pretty much what ssh-copy-id does for you, subject to some additional checks and balances.)
On the remote system, here's what we are going to execute as your root user:
umask 077
mkdir /home/new-user/.ssh
cat {new-key.pub} >/home/new/-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown new-user /home/new-user/.ssh /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Driving that from the client machine:
ssh root@10.44.32.194 '
    umask 077
    mkdir -p /home/new-user/.ssh
    cat >/home/new/-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chown new-user /home/new-user/.ssh /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
' < ~/.ssh/new-key.pub

The cat command in the middle of the set of commands will read from stdin, which is populated across the ssh connection by the source of your local new-key.pub file.
